# SQL QUERY: How to Make and use query result at multiple places in same single query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to use same query result multiple palace where all same query repeating(common query) inside query.

**Full query**

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT entityid, parententityid 
        FROM taggeditems
        INNER JOIN securitygroups
            ON entityid = securitygroups.sgentityid
        WHERE  securitygroupid IN (
            'bbe5df6a-e6be-4943-be4f-d2eafeb7ecb6',
            '5076c7f6-da01-412d-a23f-7d44a17a0c2d',
            'c01cb194-81d7-479f-9dec-5269ecd7bafa',
            '25c8eff1-1607-4a57-bd88-b4be9a1c3b73')
        AND projectname = 'MR GAT') AS A 
WHERE A.parententityid NOT IN (
    SELECT entityid 
    FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT entityid, parententityid 
            FROM taggeditems 
            INNER JOIN securitygroups
                ON entityid = securitygroups.sgentityid
            WHERE  securitygroupid IN (
                'bbe5df6a-e6be-4943-be4f-d2eafeb7ecb6',
                '5076c7f6-da01-412d-a23f-7d44a17a0c2d',
                'c01cb194-81d7-479f-9dec-5269ecd7bafa',
                '25c8eff1-1607-4a57-bd88-b4be9a1c3b73') 
            AND projectname = 'MR GAT') AS B) 
    OR A.parententityid IS NULL;
```

If we see in above query

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT entityid, parententityid
FROM taggeditems
INNER JOIN SecurityGroups
    ON entityid = SecurityGroups.SGEntityId
WHERE securityGroupId IN (
    'bbe5df6a-e6be-4943-be4f-d2eafeb7ecb6',
    '5076c7f6-da01-412d-a23f-7d44a17a0c2d',
    'c01cb194-81d7-479f-9dec-5269ecd7bafa',
    '25c8eff1-1607-4a57-bd88-b4be9a1c3b73')
AND ProjectName = 'MR GAT'
```

using two place same.Instead of i want to execute query onces and same result i can use where all further in query needed.

**i have tried like this**

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT entityid,parententityid
        FROM taggeditems
        INNER JOIN SecurityGroups
            ON entityid = SecurityGroups.SGEntityId
        WHERE securityGroupId IN (
            'bbe5df6a-e6be-4943-be4f-d2eafeb7ecb6',
            '5076c7f6-da01-412d-a23f-7d44a17a0c2d',
            'c01cb194-81d7-479f-9dec-5269ecd7bafa',
            '25c8eff1-1607-4a57-bd88-b4be9a1c3b73')
        AND ProjectName = 'MR GAT') AS A
WHERE A.parententityid NOT IN (A) AS B)
OR A.parententityid IS NULL;
```

**but error like**

```
    Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
```

How to use same query result again and again?

Comment: That's not going to work because your `A` selects two columns but your `IN` expression only supports a single column subquery (among other reasons)

Comment: If you want to reference the results of a query in more than one place, you need to use either a variable, or a temp table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Common Table Expression to reduce the repetitive parts of the query:

```
WITH FilteredItems as (
SELECT entityid,parententityid FROM taggeditems  INNER JOIN 
SecurityGroups ON entityid = SecurityGroups.SGEntityId
  WHERE securityGroupId in ('bbe5df6a-e6be-4943-be4f-d2eafeb7ecb6',
                            '5076c7f6-da01-412d-a23f-7d44a17a0c2d',
                            'c01cb194-81d7-479f-9dec-5269ecd7bafa',
                            '25c8eff1-1607-4a57-bd88-b4be9a1c3b73') and 
ProjectName = 'MR GAT'
)
SELECT distinct entityid,parententityid from FilteredItems
where parententityid not in (select entityid from FilteredItems) or parententityid is null
```

(Since `IN` is evaluating whether an entry appears in a set, it doesn't get affected by duplicates, we don't need to apply any `DISTINCT` there)